# How to put data to parsed JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, bukkit

i have some parse code and to parsed JSONObject i need  to add one more JSONObject, but getting  error `Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({)`, because my code creating multiply JSONObjects in file, not at parsed JSONObjec. Here is a code, that creating object

```
            aJson = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray blockData = new JSONArray();
            for(Block b : blocks){
                json.put("player-name", p.getName());
                json.put("uuid", p.getUniqueId().toString());
                json.put("nearestPlayers", new JSONArray());
                blockData.add(b.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
                blockData.add(b.getLocation().getWorld().getEnvironment());
                blockData.add(b.getLocation().getX());
                blockData.add(b.getLocation().getY());
                blockData.add(b.getLocation().getZ());
            }
            aJson.put(blockData, json);
```

Here is JSON
`{"[\"world\",NORMAL,-23.0,67.0,75.0]":{"player-name":"MisterFunny01","nearestPlayers":[],"uuid":"206d32da-bf72-3cfd-9a26-e374dd76da31"}} //here is that part// {"[\"world\",NORMAL,-23.0,67.0,75.0]":{"player-name":"MisterFunny01","nearestPlayers":[],"uuid":"206d32da-bf72-3cfd-9a26-e374dd76da31"},"[\"world\",NORMAL,-23.0,67.0,75.0]":{"player-name":"MisterFunny01","nearestPlayers":[],"uuid":"206d32da-bf72-3cfd-9a26-e374dd76da31"}}`

Answer (score 0):

In JSON array values must be of type string, number, object, array, boolean or null. Arrays hold values of the same type and not different types.

Looking at your code the array is an array of objects. So you would have to create an object and add the values before adding to the array.

Don't directly add values to the array but create an object and then add to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. To put an object into `JSONObject` please read [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

In your case, you need to convert `blockData` to String to put in the JSONObject.
It's like this: `aJson.put(blockData as String, json);`

Hope it can be helpful to you.

Comment: convert to JSONString, or just to default String (JSONObject.toJSONString or JSONObject.toString())?

Comment: @СашаСеменищев In your json example, the key is json string. So, you need to convert blockData to json string. Like that: `aJson.put("[\"world\",NORMAL,-23.0,67.0,75.0]", json)`

Comment: Didn't help, and if add variable directly, it automaticly converts to string, but thanks for your answer